# Error LNK 2005 Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Please help to build my project, i gave up after 2nd hour.
That is how it looks like:
[image: Solution Explorer]

```
BrickClass.h

 - #include"header.h"

header.h

 - #pragma once
 - #include windows.h
 - #include windowsX.h
 - #include tchar.h
 - #include commctrl.h
 - #include "matrixClass.h"
 - #include "resource.h"

mainClass.h

 - #include "header.h"
 - #include "brickClass.h"

matrixClass.h

 - #include cstdlib
 - #include cstdio
 - #include math.h

brickClass.cpp

 - #include "brickClass.h"

main.cpp

 - #include "mainClass.h"

mianClass.cpp

 - #include "mainClass.h"
```

[image: the error]

What i need to do to make him happy?I was tried a lot of variants but cant figure out HOW..?
Appreciate your help.
The project is Here : http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/381812/Tetris.rar

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't use header guards?

Comment: Really? An **e-mail address** is required to **download** your code?

Comment: Yes, but this is not my fileHosting )

Comment: There are code blocks integrated into the editor for a reason.

Comment: I add those flags and it doesn't help !

Comment: Please demonstrate where and how you're doing so (with actual code).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17630/discussion-between-mickey-tin-and-chris)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're giving up after the 2nd hour, this probably isn't the right industry for you :-) There'll be times when you'll have spent days trying to solve a problem, kicking yourself at the end because it was so simple in retrospect.

---

Anyway, on to the problem at hand. It's almost certainly because you have *code* in your `BrickClass` header file.

By including that header file in both `main.cpp` (via `mainClass.h`) and `BrickClass.cpp`, each of the object files gets an independent copy of the code.

Then, when you try to link those object files together, the linker finds that there are two copies.

Header files should generally contain *declarations,* like `extern int i;` or function prototypes such as `int xyzzy (void);`.

The *definitions,* like `int i;` and functions such as `int xyzzy (void) {return 42;}`, should only be placed in the "regular" source files.

Comment: this probably isn't the right industry for you :-) Its 4 me. i can spend days on "how to code" problem, but this kind of problem is *(&%^*%&

Comment: Glad to see you took the humour in the way it was intended, @Mickey, sometimes I can be an insensitive clod :-)

Comment: The definitions, like int i; and functions such as int xyzzy (void) {return 42;}, should only be placed in the "regular" source files.\n THis is the correct answer ))